# Add row that is duplicate except for one column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to write a query to add a duplicate row to a table a bit like this...

```
INSERT INTO `<table>` (column1, column2, ...) -- Not IDENTITY columns
SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM ...
```

except that the first column must have a different value in the copied row.

i.e.

```
┌─────┬────────┬────────┐
|name | weight | height |
├─────┼────────┼────────┤
│ Bob │   100  │   150  │
│     │        │        │
└─────┴────────┴────────┘
```

To

```
┌─────┬────────┬────────┐
|name | weight | height |
├─────┼────────┼────────┤
│ Bob │   100  │   150  │
│ Jim │   100  │   150  │
└─────┴────────┴────────┘
```

I can't simply insert an identical row, and then update that column, because the "name" column is unique.

Obviously in reality my table has many more columns than this example.

Comment: where are you getting the value for your unique column?

Comment: For the purpose of this example, let's say I've obtained the value elsewhere. Not really important where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
INSERT INTO `<table>` (column1, column2, ...)
SELECT 'Jim', column2, ... FROM ... WHERE ...
```